# Get timestamps for "IN" and "OUT" rows for matching "user id"s

Tags: mysql

I am using a mySQL database and I have records in it. What I want to do is to take the TIME-IN and TIME-OUT of a person in a table and display it in an HTML table.

I am using PHP here, and I don't know how to create a query for this.
This is the data in my table.

tblaccess_event_logs

```
USERID | User_FirstName | User_LastName | EVENTID | LOCAL_TIMESTAMP(Y-m-d) |
2222   |   Zack         |     Hewit     |   IN    |  2014-10-09 08:30:00
2222   |   Zack         |     Hewit     |   OUT   |  2014-10-09 17:30:00
```

This is the output I want:

```
USERID | User_FirstName | User_LastName |       IN         |    OUT    |
2222   |   Zack         |     Hewit     |   09 08:30:00    |  17:30:00 |
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work..

```
 select USERID,User_FirstName,User_LastName, 
   time(min(LOCAL_TIMESTAMP(Y-m-d))) as In, # get the time part 
   time(Max(LOCAL_TIMESTAMP(Y-m-d))) as out # get the time part 
 from tblaccess_event_logs
 group by USERID,User_FirstName,User_LastName
```

Answer (score 0):

try this.....

```
SELECT USERID,
       User_FirstName,
       User_LastName, 
       MIN(LOCAL_TIMESTAMP(Y-m-d)) AS IN, 
       MAX(LOCAL_TIMESTAMP(Y-m-d)) AS OUT 
FROM tblaccess_event_logs
GROUP BY USERID
```

this will work if zack is having 1 in and 1 out only, but what if zach have 2 log in and 2 log out?
having `log_id` field in yout table will be a great help in the near future.